# JSF 2 - calling a listener with object parameter from composite component

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I have the following question:
I defined my own custom component this way:

```
<composite:interface componentType="myComponent">
   <composite:attribute name="listener" method-signature="void action(java.lang.Object)"/>
   ...
   more attributues
</composite:interface>
```

Now, in my view, i try to pass a listener with a specific cellphone object that was passed to the view via ui:param tag:

```
<ui:include src="page.xhtml" >
     <ui:param name="currentCellphone" value="#{cellphone}" />
</ui:include>
```

and then, in the page.xhtml view, i try to do:

```
<my:myComponent ... listener = "#{backbeanController.backbeanMethod(currentCellphone)}">
```

Now, if the backbeanmethod is expecting to get a cellphone object as a parameter, when it's gets to the function, the parameter is **null.** But!, if it's excepted to get string for example, and i send it a string instead of myCellphone object, is works just fine.

I can't pass the myCellphone parameter properly to the backbean. any ideas? Thank you very much.

Comment: Every thing you said is correct you can't send object you only can send String and retrieve it

Comment: You can work with sessionMap if you want

Comment: thanks.so you think there is no other way to send object from view to bean?

Comment: I told you you can use session map you can see a perfect example here http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=40250

Comment: would you like an example ???

Comment: no, i think i am good. thanks a lot!

Comment: i will post this link as an answer of this question is it OK for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass complex object as a parameter, you can just pass a string, say "Id" of the object. Then you have to reconstruct the object but you can use session map like in this example :

```
Map<String, Object> sessionMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap();
sessionMap.put("controller", controller);
```

and call it

```
Map<String, Object> sessionMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap();
MyController controller = (MyController) sessionMap.get("controller");
```

You can read the complete example in [Primefaces forum](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=40250) alse see [Other link](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=41689)

Hope that helped you.

Comment: @mayyuval here are the answer fill free to add if something is missing

Comment: @mayyuval do not forget to make it as an answer